# Looking for a proof of a geometric regularity criteria: generalization of the exterior cone condition / Zaremba's criterion

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity

The topic is Perron's method for the Dirichlet problem.
I am looking for a proof of the following statement:

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 3$ and $0 \in \partial \Omega$. If any $x \in \Omega$ near $0$ satisfies $x_n < f(|x'|)$, where $x'=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ and $f(r)=ar^{1/m}$ for some $a>0$ and $m>0$, then the point $0$ is regular, i.e. there exists a local barrier.

I found this statement in a [paper by Gantumur](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f14/perron.pdf) on page 7, remark 10, which is apparently due to Lebesgue. The case $m=1$ is known as Zaremba's criterion or the exterior cone condition. In the same paper below the statement Gantumur writes that it is not true if $f(r)=a/\log\frac{1}{r}$ which he prooves. That example is also known as the Lebesgue spine.

I've looked into the following books:
David H. Armitage, Stephen J. Gardiner - Classical Potential Theory (2001):
There is only a proof for $m=1$ (6.6.15) and a proof that $0$ in the Lebesgue spine is irregular (6.6.17).
L.L. Helms - Potential Theory (2014):
There is only a proof for $m=1$ (3.6.29) and a proof that $0$ in the Lebesgue spine is irregular (4.4.11). 
ABR - Harmonic Function Theory (2001):
There is only a proof for $m=1$ (11.16).

But I've not yet encountered a proof for the general case $m>0$.

Has someone a proof or know where I can find one?

Comment: Alright I found out the statement is not true for $n \geq 4$, because for the monotone function $f(t)=t^m$ we have $\int_0^1 t^{2-n}(t^m)^{n-3}\mathrm{d}t<\infty$ with $n \geq 4$ and that implies irregularity (c.f.David H. Armitage, Stephen J. Gardiner - Classical Potential Theory (2001) Theorem 6.6.16 on page 186). I think it is true for $n=3$ but here we are again, I don't have any proof.